# timer._repeat is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

node v4.2.6

I have a small program:

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
var _ = require('lodash');
var q = require('q');
var fs = require('fs');
var faker = require('faker');
var file = 'testfile.txt';
var pending = '';
var writer;

fs.open(file,'w+',function(){
    writer = fs.createWriteStream(file);

    writer.on('error',function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });

    writer.on('drain',rewrite);

    var timer = setInterval(write(),100);
});

function write(){
    var data = faker.Helpers.createCard();
    console.log('attempting to write ' + Buffer.byteLength(data,'utf8') + ' bytes');
    var ok = writer.write(data.toString());
    if(!ok){
        console.log('buffer full, saving in memory');
        pending += data;
    }else{
        console.log('written');
    }
}

function rewrite(){
    console.log('buffer empty, writing ' + Buffer.byteLength(data,'utf8') + ' bytes from memory');
    var ok = writer.write(pending);
    if(!ok){
        console.log('buffer full again. Saving in memory again');
        pending += data;
    }
}
```

After it writes the first few bytes to the file, it errors out with:

```
timers.js:275
    timer._repeat();
          ^

TypeError: timer._repeat is not a function
    at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:275:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

What's going wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: You should be passing `write` not `write()` to `setInterval()`. That's not the immediate problem; what is "timers.js"?

Comment: @Pointy oh yeah. Good spot

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This:

```
var timer = setInterval(write(),100);
```

is passing the *result* of `write()` as the function to be called every 100 milliseconds. `write()` doesn't return a function (`undefined` is implicitly returned), so you get the `TypeError`. Instead, pass the function itself:

```
var timer = setInterval(write,100);
```